# Scala override error

Tags: scala, playframework, securesocial

I am using Play framework 2.2.x and SecureSocial and for testing I am trying to override a method in a superclass. Actually I am getting a compile error using the test helper classes from secure social and I can not figure it out as I am not all that familiar with Scala.

What I don't understand is why my ide things the method is correctly overridden but when I compile I get the error. I know scala is not that well  integrated with the ides but I can not see why the override is incorrect.

```
/**
 *  This is the secure social class and method I am trying to override. 
    I have left the other methods out for clarity. The problem method is the doAuth method
 **/
```

package securesocial.core

```
import providers.utils.RoutesHelper
import play.api.mvc.{SimpleResult, AnyContent, Request}
import play.api.{Play, Application, Plugin}
import concurrent.{Await, Future}
import play.api.libs.ws.Response

abstract class IdentityProvider(application: Application) extends Plugin with Registrable {
 /**
   * Subclasses need to implement the authentication logic. This method needs to return
   * a User object that then gets passed to the fillProfile method
   *
   * @param request
   * @return Either a Result or a User
   * This is the method I am having trouble trying to override
   */
  def doAuth()(implicit request: Request[AnyContent]):Either[SimpleResult, SocialUser]
}
```

This is the my class and the doAuth() override 
    package testkit

```
import play.api.Logger
import securesocial.core._
import play.api.mvc.{Result, Request}
import securesocial.core.IdentityId

class AlwaysValidIdentityProvider(app:play.api.Application) extends IdentityProvider(app){
  val logger = Logger("securesocial.stubs.AlwaysValidIdentityProvider")
  def authMethod: AuthenticationMethod = AuthenticationMethod("naive")


  override def doAuth()(implicit request: Request[play.api.mvc.AnyContent]): Either[Result, SocialUser] ={
    val userId = request.body.toString
    val r =Right(SocialUserGenerator.socialUserGen(IdentityId(userId, id), authMethod).sample.get)
    r
  }


  def fillProfile(user: SocialUser): SocialUser = {
    user
  }

  def id: String = "naive"
}
```

The error I am getting is: As you can see it thinks I am overriding nothing.

```
[error] /Users/zola/Development/play/receipt-manager/rm-play/test/testkit/AlwaysValidIdentityProvider.scala:8: class AlwaysValidIdentityProvider needs to be abstract, since method doAuth in class IdentityProvider of type [A]()(implicit request: play.api.mvc.Request[A])Either[play.api.mvc.Result,securesocial.core.SocialUser] is not defined
[error] class AlwaysValidIdentityProvider(app:play.api.Application) extends IdentityProvider(app){
[error]       ^
[error] /Users/zola/Development/play/receipt-manager/rm-play/test/testkit/AlwaysValidIdentityProvider.scala:13: method doAuth overrides nothing.
[error] Note: the super classes of class AlwaysValidIdentityProvider contain the following, non final members named doAuth:
[error] def doAuth[A]()(implicit request: play.api.mvc.Request[A]): Either[play.api.mvc.Result,securesocial.core.SocialUser]
[error]   override def doAuth()(implicit request: Request[play.api.mvc.AnyContent]): Either[Result, SocialUser] ={
[error]                ^
[error] two errors found
```

Comment: Isn't it because the return types are different? E.g. `Result` and `SimpleResult`.

Answer (score 1):

That's because the method you are overriding is not already defined. You have a signature in the abstract class and that's it.

Try this instead:

```
def doAuth()(implicit request: Request[play.api.mvc.AnyContent]): Either[Result, SocialUser] ={
    val userId = request.body.toString
    val r =Right(SocialUserGenerator.socialUserGen(IdentityId(userId, id), authMethod).sample.get)
    r
}
```

Comment: So the one in the abstract class is not under my control it belongs to the SecureSocial framework so I can't change it

Comment: Actually, the one that is in the abstract class is just a signature showing the arguments and return type. Basically by inheriting from the abstract class you have to provide your own implementation of it. You can later instantiate an object of your class that will use your implementation. Overriding is used when you already have an implementation defined in the parent abstract class.

Comment: Thanks Peter, I fully grasp the concept of overriding I just can't see why it has an error when I try to override this one. So even with your suggestion I get an error in the ide saying its not overriding the superclass method and if I auto implement it within the ide is fine in the ide but when I compile I get the above error.

Answer (score 1):

To solve the issue I looked at other classes within SecureSocial and they way they implemented the method was

```
    def doAuth[A]()(implicit request: Request[A]): Either[Result, SocialUser] = {
     val userId = request.body.toString
     val r =Right(SocialUserGenerator.socialUserGen(IdentityId(userId, id), authMethod).sample.get)
     r
 }
```